# Updating react context causes infinite render loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

It's seems like my useEffect hook triggers an infinite rerender loop whenever I try to update the context within it. I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone give me any pointers as to how to solve this or what causes the loop?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-cohen-mjvvg?file=/src/components/Input.tsx:440-555

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `Predication` component.  Never call `setState()` directly inside functional component. If you want to do some work when some props change, you should use `useEffect` hooks and pass the props as dependencies for it. Never call `setState` directly inside the function component, you can think never call `this.setState()` in `render()` method of a class component.

```
// Call API when the `input.text` and `input.model` changed
useEffect(() => {
    if (input.text && input.model) {
      console.log("predict");
      predict(input.text, input.model)
        .then((res) => setPrediction(res))
        .catch((e) => <p>Noe gikk galt. Prøv igjen senere</p>);
    }
  }, [input.text, input.model]);

// Never do this, `setPrediction` will make the component re-render and cause the infinite loop.
  // Predict if text
  // if (input.text && input.model) {
  // console.log("predict");
  // predict(input.text, input.model)
  //   .then((res) => setPrediction(res))
  //   .catch((e) => <p>Noe gikk galt. Prøv igjen senere</p>);
  // }
```

Besides, you should declare the state before using it in your `InputContextProvider` component.

```
export const InputContextProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    text: "",
    model: "bayes"
  });

  // TODO: Replace any type
  const setInput = (input: any) => {
    setState({ ...state, text: input.text, model: input.model });
  };

  return (
    <InputContext.Provider value={{ ...state, setInput }}>
      {props.children}
    </InputContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-flower-0hgey?file=/src/components/Prediction.tsx:786-1294)

Answer (score 0):

this is not the recommended way to update context:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    inputContext.setInput({ text: debouncedText, model: debouncedText });
  }, [debouncedText, model]);
```

because once you setInput, you caused inputContext changed, and once you cause the inputContext changed, it will trigger inputContext.setInput again.. this will cause an infinite update util stack overflow.

In your case, I think you could update context by setting an additional state to mark whether debouncedText, debouncedText have changed or not.

```
  const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!changed) {
        inputContext.setInput({ text: debouncedText, model: debouncedText });
        setChanged(true)
    } 
  }, [debouncedText, model, change, setChanged]);
```